# Custom text for the empty cell above the header name cell for autoGroupColumnDef ag-grid angular

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

| (blank) | Row A | Row B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Header Name1 | Header Name2 | Header Name3 |
| ------------ | ------------ | ------------ |
| field 1 | field 3 | field 5 |
| ------------ | ------------ | ------------ |
| field 2 | field 4 | field 6 |

This is the table when I run the application. I would like to put a custom value (string) on the (**blank**) cell above **Header Name1**.

note: Header Name 1 and the fields under it are under **autoGroupColumnDef**.

I have this as my code:

```
let ColumnDefinition: (ColDef | ColGroupDef) = {
  field: 'field',
  headerName: 'Header Name1',
  sortable: true,
  width: 375,
  type: ['centerAligned'],
  filter: 'agTextColumnFilter',
  pinned: 'left',
  suppressSizeToFit: true,
  cellRendererFramework: CellRenderingComponent,
  cellRendererParams: {rowData: this.rowData, country: this.Country}
}
this.transformDataForRollups();
this.autoGroupColumnDef = ColumnDefinition;
this.gridOptions = {
  autoGroupColumnDef: this.autoGroupColumnDef,
  defaultColDef: this.defaultColDef,
  columnDefs: this.columnDefs,
  rowData: this.rowData,
  defaultColGroupDef: this.defaultColGroupDef,
  columnTypes: this.columnTypes,
  animateRows: true,
  treeData:true,
  singleClickEdit: true,
  context: {componentParent: this},
  getDataPath: this.getDataPath
};
```